# Can't get some data with SNMPv3

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have to change from snmp v2c to snmp v3.

With snmp v2c, if I run the follow command line:

```
$ snmpwalk -c MyCom -v 2c 10.10.6.2 sysUpTime
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (44765283) 5 days, 4:20:52.83
```

I can get the systemUptime

But after config snmpv v3 in the same devide (Switch HP A5120)

```
$ snmpwalk -v3 -u UserSnmp -l AuthNoPriv -a MD5 -A 'SnmpPAss' 10.10.6.2 sysUpTime
SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

If i run `snmpwalk -v3 -u UserSnmp -l AuthNoPriv -a MD5 -A 'SnmpPAss' 10.10.6.2` I receive a list of OID, the problem occurs only for item under sys table

I tried to find specific MIB for snmpv3 but I can't find anyone. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not related with MIB or snmpwalk command.

The config on switch was wrong, the snmp user was not allowed to see some specific OID's.